# Does FSI deal well with multi module F# projects?

Tags: .net, f#, fsi

Does FSI deal well with multi module/file F# projects?
Consider the following project:

*module.fs:*

```
module Xyz

let add x y = x + y
```

*Program.fs:*

```
module Program

open Xyz    
let result = add 1 2
```

selecting and running the last 2 lines of `Program.fs` will yield the following FSI error:

```
Program.fs: error FS0039: The namespace or module 'Xyz' is not defined
```

What is the problem here?

---

So, let's say I have the following project structure:

```
A.fs
B.fs
C.fs
D.fs
E.fs
```

I want to run some functions of `E.fs`. `E.fs` makes use of all the other `.fs` files, so I have one `open` for each one of them. If later on I want to also run some code from any one of the other files, I'll have to repeat the process fo any file that was not `#loaded` before.

From your suggestions, it seems like to make my `E.fs` file run on FSI I'll either have to create a separate .fsx file or have a separate

```
#if INTERACTIVE
#load "..."
```

for each module I'll use which is IMO quite redundant. Am I missing something here, or is this a clear violation of both KISS and DRY principles?

Answer (score 4):

The error will be because you have not loaded the file - it works fine for me doing

```
 $ fsi --load:module.fs --load:Program.fs

Microsoft (R) F# 2.0 Interactive build 2.0.0.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

For help type #help;;

[Loading /suphys/jpal8929/fsbug/module.fs
 Loading /suphys/jpal8929/fsbug/Program.fs]

namespace FSI_0002
  val add : int -> int -> int


namespace FSI_0002
  val result : int

>
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. But isn't there something *easier*? I mean, let's say I have this huge file that opens 5, 6 modules. Better yet, imagine I have this big project where I want to run a couple of functions in file X, a couple of functions in file Y, etc from FSI. If I have to manually load every file each one of those files use it gets really easily tiresome. I guess there must be some other way of achieving this..? Unless F#'s purpose is nothing but single file "projects", I'm finding this extremely awkward. (I'm using FSI from Visual Studio, btw).

Comment: @devoured - you can write a script.fsx file with contents `#load "module.fs";;` to easily load the files

Comment: The problem is that I don't see what is *easy* in the approach described. See the edit of my original post.

Comment: @devoured The real problem is if you have many files, the order f\the files are included will have an effect on the ouput (consider 2 files which both define an add function).  As a result Visual Studio cannot possibly do this in the correct order.  An alternative is to compile everything to a dll/exe and then you can load the DLL with `#r...` which only needs 1 call per dll which could have multiple files

Comment: @devouredelysium if you use VSCode and install the Ionide-fsharp extension, you can select the "FSI: Generate script file..." options from the Ctrl+Shift+P menu, and that'll create an `fsx` file for you with all the correct `#r` and `#load` directives, that can be pretty handy.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few options, some of them already mentioned by Brian and jpalmer, so I'll just try to summarize:

- If you have just a few files, then you can "load" them, which means that the source gets sent to F# Interactive and is compiled in the FSI console. This approach is useful if you want to test a part of a larger project.

  To do this, you can either use `--load:file.fs` command line option or you can write `#load "file.fs"` in F# Interactive (or in a `Script.fsx` file that is sent to F# Interactive using `--load`). To manage more files, you can write a script `Load.fsx` that loads all the files you need.
- If you have a larger project (e.g. a library) and want to use it or test it from F# Interactive, then you can compile the library using `fsc.exe`, reference it from F# Interactive and use its public types/functions from the console

  To do this, you can either use `-r:MyLib.dll` command line option, or you can write `#r "MyLib.dll` in F# Interactive (or in an `fsx` script file).

Answer (score 2):

Are you aware of `#load`?  Are you aware of `#r` (after compiling other code into a DLL)?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233175.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Create an .fsx file that begins:

```
#load "module.fs" "Program.fs"
```

and run that from FSI first to get your code loaded.